# Add text into a list item when selected using jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, list, text

I am using jQuery UI  dragable and sortable, when I click the item to move, I want to be able to add text inside an li it shows where to place the item, I have setup the below to demonstrate:' -

http://jsfiddle.net/uJcB7/191/

Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bind sortable's [`start`](http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/#event-start) event:

```
$(function() {
    $( "#sortable" ).sortable({
        placeholder: "ui-state-highlight",
        start: function(event, ui) { 
          $("li.ui-state-highlight").text("your text");
        }
    });
    $( "#sortable" ).disableSelection();
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uJcB7/191/).
​

Answer (score 0):

```
    $("li").click(function(){
            $(this).text("PLACE ON :" + place);
    });
```