# jQuery UI sortable plus showing the ID and value

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have a list of items using sortable jquery.and each item has a value (first,second,third) and each vaue an ID (1,2,3)

I want when the user moves first to position third, the id of first should be 3 and that of third should be 1. and I want the id to be displayed next to the value

**example:**

- first-1
- second-2
- third-3

**..after changing position:**

- third-1
- second-2
- first-3

---

this is my javascript

```
$(function () {
    $('#sortable').sortable({
        //to prevent items from moving around when draging
        containment: "parent",
        start: function (event, ui) {
            // get the initial position(index) of item
            var start_pos = ui.item.index();
            ui.item.data('start_pos', start_pos);

        },

        update: function (event, ui) {
            var index = ui.item.index();
            var start_pos = ui.item.data('start_pos');

            //update the html of the moved item to the current index
            $('#sortable li:nth-child(' + (index + 1) + ')').appendTo(index);

            if (start_pos < index) {
                //update the items before the re-ordered item
                for (var i = index; i > 0; i--) {
                    $('#sortable li:nth-child(' + i + ')').appendTo(i - 1);
                }
            } else {
                //update the items after the re-ordered item
                for (var i = index + 2; i <= $("#sortable li").length; i++) {
                    $('#sortable li:nth-child(' + i + ')').appendTo(i - 1);

                }
            }
        },
        axis: 'y'
    });
});
```

and my html:

```
<div class="container">
    <ul id="sortable" class="ui-sortable">
        <li id="sort_1" class="ui-state-default">first -</li>
        <li id="sort_2" class="ui-state-default">second -</li>
        <li id="sort_3" class="ui-state-default">third -</li>
        <li id="sort_4" class="ui-state-default">fourth -</li>
        <li id="sort_5" class="ui-state-default">fifth -</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: i can sort but can't display the id

Comment: please anyone i really need help with this

Comment: Why reinvent the wheel? Since you use JQUery, you might as well use JQuery UI: http://jqueryui.com/sortable/

Comment: how can i display the id next to the value?

Comment: We're not here to code for you. Nor to do research for you. var id = $('#sortable li:nth-child('+i+')').attr('id); http://api.jquery.com/attr/

Comment: im coding for myself im just asking for help

Comment: I don't mean to be rude. But a little Google or SO research on your own is required, especially for something as common as retrieving the id of an element with JQuery. Is it just the ID, or does your script not work at all?

Comment: i have been googling since yesterday and won't find a solution by the way im very fresh to javascript and jquery its my first week so if you want to help thanks a lot if not also thank for your concern.i can sort because im alerting the index and its correct i just want to display that index i dont know how

Comment: appendTo may be the culprit. As JQuery say : "Insert every element in the set of matched elements to the end of the target.". So your code probably works, but it is appended after </li>, so something between </li> and <li> cannot be displayed by a browser.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12054074/add-text-into-a-list-item-when-selected-using-jquery